# Passwordless access to psql from Administrator WITHOUT any password (Windows)

Tags: postgresql, authentication

Yes, I know there are plenty of answers on how to access `psql` without password... while specifying password somewhere.

I do not have context this luxurious. I do **not** have any password. What I do have is access to `Administrator` account on Windows.

My job is gathering meta-information about PostgreSQL installation (version, data directory, configuration file and plenty of other aspects, some of which are most conveniently gathered via `psql` queries).

Any and all passwords are **not** accessible to me. The diagnostics is ran by an agent running as superuser, `Administrator` on Windows. The agent is part of a larger package of software for management and diagnostics of large number of endpoints, including but not limited to Windows endpoints. I am *not* accessing those PG installations as a DBA that has a password somewhere for a few hosts or can ask someone to give them passwords. Passwords for me are strictly off limits.

I'll have to ask yet but most likely I'm not at liberty of changing `pg_hba.conf` or other database files either.

On Linux this is trivial: I run `/bin/su - postgres ...` command and get what I need on basis of `ident` authentication.

No such luck on Windows.

This seems strange to me: I have superuser account... yet I don't have password-less access to Postgres. On Windows only.

As far as I could tell on most hosts there is no equivalent `postgres` user to default out-of-box Linux installations. There's only `Administrator`.

So.. is there a way to run psql / SQL queries on Windows in PG without password? I'm so desperate I'm considering using C# or C++ and going low-level even if that solves my problem.

Comment: You want to change how PostgreSQL authentication behaves, but you don't want to change PostgreSQL's configuration? Forget it. Try to come up with more reasonable requirements.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe It's not that I don't want to do it, I'm forbidden from doing it. I'm not allowed to change anything on a production host.

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have sounded like I was blaming you. You will have to tell whomever wants you to do this that it cannot be done. If the database is configured not to let you in without authentication, you cannot do that, at least not without changing the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL on Windows does not support "peer" authentication method, which is what I assume you mean by "ident" as "ident" itself is rarely used (and I wouldn't trust it much if it were used).

Also, Windows does support the "local" connection over Unix-domain sockets as of v13 but it is not configured to be active by default and Windows clients don't default to using it, so you would need to manually specify the socket path using `-h`.  And if it were to be used, then without "peer" it would still need a password to be secure, or you would need to place the socket file someplace where no one but the superuser can access it.